# How to get the last modification date for Contacts list (Add/Delete/Modify)

Tags: android, contacts

How can i know the last date the Contacts table was modiefied at? i have tried `ContactsContract.RawContacts.VERSION` and `CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP` but it seems that these are used to know the modified date for a single contact, and it is not working well with me. how can i get the last modified date for any contact in the contacts List

Comment: in witch version ? I don't have answer but android version can influence that I guest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last i have made an array String in all the Versions of the Contacts i have, since it is the same this means that the Contacts table has not been changed, i have not found any other way, this is my Code

```
private String sGetCurrentContatcsVersions() {

        Cursor allContacts = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        StringBuilder sbCurrentVersion = new StringBuilder();
        allContacts.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < allContacts.getCount(); i++) {

            if (!TimelineService.bScannerIsRunning) {
                break;
            }
            int col = allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.VERSION);
            sbCurrentVersion.append(allContacts.getString(col));
            allContacts.moveToNext();
        }

        return sbCurrentVersion.toString();
    }
```

Comment: If allContacts's order changes... something might be wrong.

Comment: Would you also get the phone number as well?