# How can I get contact saved date in android?

Tags: android

For Name of a contact :

```
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
```

For Number of a contact :

```
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
```

For Date (Inserted Date) of a contact :
   Here i need a date of particular contact when inserted...  Any help ??

Comment: Check out the similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702547/how-to-get-the-last-modification-date-for-contacts-list-add-delete-modify

Comment: @GrIsHu: I dont want last modification date, i need initial date of contact added..

Comment: AFAIK There is no such method to get the initial date of contact.